# Deadlock when appending same table

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, deadlock, jooq, database-deadlocks

I have a simple table that consists of 3 FK

```
CREATE TABLE static_group_content (
    group_id bigint NOT NULL,
    member_id bigint NOT NULL,
    subgraph_id bigint,

    CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY(group_id, member_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_1 FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES group(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_2 FOREIGN KEY (member_id) REFERENCES named_objects(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_3 FOREIGN KEY (subgraph_id) REFERENCES subgraph(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

and Im getting deadlock when I'm inserting into from 2 different transaction

postgres log:

```
17:47:34.503 UTC [458] ERROR:  deadlock detected
17:47:34.503 UTC [458] DETAIL:  Process 458 waits for ShareLock on transaction 5949; blocked by process 454.
    Process 454 waits for ShareLock on transaction 5946; blocked by process 458.
    Process 458: insert into "public"."static_group_content" ("group_id", "member_id", "subgraph_id") values ($1, $2, $3)
    Process 454: insert into "public"."static_group_content" ("group_id", "member_id", "subgraph_id") values ($1, $2, $3)
17:47:34.503 UTC [458] HINT:  See server log for query details.
17:47:34.503 UTC [458] CONTEXT:  while locking tuple (1,61) in relation "named_objects"
```

details from jdbc log:

```
 Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into "public"."static_group_content" ("group_id", "member_id", "subgraph_id") values (1065, 16, 2) was aborted: ERROR: deadlock detected
   Detail: Process 191 waits for ShareLock on transaction 2428; blocked by process 192.
 Process 192 waits for ShareLock on transaction 2424; blocked by process 191.
   Hint: See server log for query details.
   Where: while locking tuple (0,154) in relation "named_objects"
 SQL statement "SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "public"."named_objects" x WHERE "uid" OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) $1 FOR KEY SHARE OF x"  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
```

postgres documentations says:

> The INSERT statements take a FOR KEY SHARE lock on the referenced rows
> in parent. That is necessary so that no concurrent transaction can
> delete the row referenced by our not yet committed INSERT. As you can
> see in the compatibility matrix, these locks don’t conflict with each
> other.

but 'FOR KEY SHARE' lock only conflicts with 'FOR UPDATE' and I do not have any explicit 'FOR UPDATE' in my code (I'm using jOOQ)

[image]

Why it may happen? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 15.1

Comment: it used to be 14.3, but still reproducible on 15.1

Comment: I don't think this can happen is those statements were the only statements in their transactions.  But it would be easy to get it if each session issued a FOR UPDATE earlier in the each transaction.  Maybe JOOQ implicitly adds FOR UPDATE to something.  If you set log_statement=all, you can see if there are FOR UPDATES in any statements sent.

Comment: @jjanes: jOOQ doesn't implicitly add `FOR UPDATE` clauses unless the user adds it to a jOOQ query.

Comment: im stupid, looks like it is caused by DELETE from "named_objects"

Comment: nope, it still happens , even without that DELETE

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused by the bug in my code records referenced by FOREIGN KEY
were deleted in another transaction.
I have not idea why error says that one insert is blocked by another one